# Is it possible to (and how can I) setup keychain to use forwarded agent?

Tags: ssh

Like a good and secure little citizen, I have `keychain --clear` in my .zlogin file. However, I have 2-3 systems that a routinely access. Now, through my ssh config, I have forwarding agent set up. So I might connect from `A->B->C`. Now, both B and C have the same authorized_keys file.

Here's what I envision working (or something like it):

Let's say I make a password connection to `B`. It should drop any previous keys and ask me for the new password. Then I ssh from there to `C`. Now `C` drops its keys, but since I'm using forwarding, `C` should be using the keys from `B`. So I finish my work on `C` and log out, but it should *keep* the keys forwarded from `B`. So it might look something like this:

```
Host  ->   Key
B     ->   B
C     ->   B
```

Later on, I'm working on host `A` and I connect to `B` (with agent forwarding, of course). So now I've got:

```
A     ->   A
B     ->   A
C     ->   B
```

Then I go ahead and ssh to C. Now all three servers should be using the same key. And when I `exit` all the way out, they should all be using the same key.

Is this possible? And if so how can I do it? And if this isn't terribly secure, what would make for a better method?

Comment: What would make for a better method depends on what you wish to accomplish by this method. What is the goal?

Comment: The goal is to stop having to unlock my keys on my other machines - I'm perfectly happy with them storing the forwarded agent key after I log out.